# getting the JSON string in the console and storing it in a variable

Tags: objective-c, xcode

how to read and store the `JSON` string in one variable which is in console...actually while i am calling one javascript function which is in index.html file from appdelegate i am getting the following `JSON` structure response,

```
[
   "registerDevice",
   {
      "type":"7",
      "pushBadge":"1",
      "pushSound":"1",
      "enabled":"1",
      "dev‌ iceToken":"e03d25f4f1bd40678cd693fe66fe7946ffdb03e1b23cfc5f9dc747fd5869fbcd",
      "pus‌ hAlert":"1"
   }
]
```

i need that device token value alone to store in one variable....how can i do that...thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
[
"registerDevice",
{
    "type": "7",
    "pushBadge": "1",
    "pushSound": "1",
    "enabled": "1",
    "dev‌iceToken": "e03d25f4f1bd40678cd693fe66fe7946ffdb03e1b23cfc5f9dc747fd5869fbcd",
    "pus‌ hAlert": "1"
}
```

]

Try this code:

```
NSArray *jsonArr = [responseStr JSONValue]; //your JSON response

NSDictionary *dicObj = (NSDictionary*)[jsonArr objectAtIndex:1];

NSString *deviceToken = [dicObj objectForKey:@"dev‌iceToken"];
```

This will definitely help you.

If it helps you, please mark it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Most Browser Support `Json.parse()` function.
so,You can use

```
var json = '{"result":true,"count":1}',
    abc = JSON.parse(json);

alert(abc.count);
```

You can access your json response value using abc.
Hope i have given your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `NSJSONSerialization` you can parse json response.

Try this way,

```
NSString *str = @"[\"registerDevice\",{\"dev‌ iceToken\":\"e03d25f4f1bd40678cd693fe66fe7946ffdb03e1b23cfc5f9dc747fd5869fbcd\",\"pus‌ hAlert\":\"1\"}]";
NSError *jsonError = nil;
id allValues = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                                                   options:0
                                                     error:&jsonError];
NSString *deviceToken = [allValues[1] objectForKey:@"dev‌ iceToken"];
NSLog(@"deviceToken: %@",deviceToken);
```

*Note: Instead of 'str' replace you 'json response'.*

Comment: but in the JSON response we don't have any separators,how can we insert that,without separators it will not work right?

Comment: which separators you talking about ? BTW you must have valid json before parsing it.

Comment: back slashes...we don't have that in JSON response know

Comment: can you tell me how to read that directly from console and storing in one variable without hardcoding it

Comment: How you are printing JSON response in console ? using NSLog right ? means you have json string right ?

Comment: no,i am calling one method which is in some other javascript file from app delegate that will give the JSON response in console using console.log in javascript file

Comment: I guess there must be some mechanism to read and store data from that js file . Look on that.